# Multidimensional Associate Array in C#

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

I am completely new to C#. I am a PHP programmer. So please bear with me.

I have an XML with the following in it:

```
<setting name="event1" color="white" align="center" />
<setting name="event2" color="red" align="left" />
```

I have already figured out how to get the information, using XmlReader GetAttribute, but I have absolutely no idea how to store it into an array. The final array I would like to have would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [event1] => Array
    (
        [color] => white
        [align] => center
    )
    [event2] => Array
    (
        [color] => red
        [align] => left
    )
)
```

So if I wanted to access the information from an array called "settings", I would use:

```
settings["event1"]["color"] = "white";
```

How would I do something like this in C#? Bear in mind I am completely new to C#.

----- EDIT

I have tried adding a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace xSplit_Panel_Writer
{
    class Settings
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Align { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I am having issues getting it working in my actual script...

```
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data/config.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "setting"))
                {
                    var settings = new Dictionary<string, Settings>();
                    settings.Add(reader.Name, reader);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,xSplit_Panel_Writer.Settings>.Add(string, xSplit_Panel_Writer.Settings)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\Jaxel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\xSplit Panel Writer\xSplit Panel Writer\MainForm.cs    31  25  xSplit Panel Writer
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlReader' to 'xSplit_Panel_Writer.Settings'    C:\Users\Jaxel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\xSplit Panel Writer\xSplit Panel Writer\MainForm.cs    31  51  xSplit Panel Writer
```

Comment: You've gotten some Dictionary<string, Dict<string, string>> answers, but do you need late bound access? Or would 'settings["event"].color  be just as good for your needs?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was asking if creating a an object to hold the attributes (i.e. an early bound option) would be useful. The answer provided by @Anthony_Pegram addresses this idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the attributes in your XML are static, I would instead opt to create a class to encapsulate your data. This will give you a strongly typed object with properties  you can code against, getting full compile-time support, intellisense, etc.

```
class Setting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Align { get; set; }
}
```

And you can then populate instances of this class with your data, create a list of them, or even perhaps load those into a dictionary, using the Name as the key.

```
var setting = LoadSettingFromXml();
var settings = new Dictionary<string, Setting>();
settings.Add(setting.Name, setting); 

// elsewhere
settings["event1"].Color = "blue";
```

You could go from there to learn about using Linq-to-Xml to read your XML into these objects and further into the collection type you prefer.

---

A full blown code example. Given the class as defined above and a valid XML snippet

```
string xml = @" <settings>
                    <setting name=""event1"" color=""white"" align=""center"" /> 
                    <setting name=""event2"" color=""red"" align=""left"" />
                </settings>";
```

You can use Linq-to-Xml to parse the document to a sequence of objects.

```
// can also use XDocument.Load(...) to load from a file or stream.
var document = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
var settingsList = (from element in document.Root.Elements("setting")
                    select new Setting
                    {
                        Name = element.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Color = element.Attribute("color").Value,
                        Align = element.Attribute("align").Value
                    }).ToList();
```

You can further transform this into a dictionary. First, showing creating the dictionary "the long way" with a loop.

```
var settingsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Setting>();
foreach (var setting in settingsList)
{
    settingsDictionary.Add(setting.Name, setting);
}
```

But you can also use Linq to transform the sequence to a dictionary without the explicit loop.

```
var settingsDictionary = settingsList.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s);
```

As reference, the Linq code requires .NET 3.5+ (C# 3.0+, Visual Studio 2008+ editions), and references to System.Core.dll, System.Xml.Linq.dll, and using directives for System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq. The DLLs will be referenced by default in most new solutions created in Visual Studio.

Comment: This won't work if the list of properties is dynamic. It's hard to tell whether that actually is the case, or whether it's just the OP's background in PHP showing.

Comment: Valid point, added a "static" disclaimer to lead off the answer.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod, updated to show a full code sample using Linq.

Comment: This is all so confusing... even with you laying it out, I can't understand any of it. Dealing with C# is giving me new found respect for PHP. This entire thing would take 2 lines in PHP.

Comment: I am now getting this error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Setting' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Jaxel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\xSplit Panel Writer\xSplit Panel Writer\MainForm.cs 26 44 xSplit Panel Writer

Comment: Have you defined the class? Reading the error message, have you added a using directive for the namespace? I understand that you are new with C#. Take some time to wade into it more. It's different than PHP. That comes with advantages and disadvantages. But right now, the main disadvantage for you is an understandable lack of familiarity.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod - this solution relies on generics & LINQ.  Conceptually these are pretty far removed from PHP's though process.  Once i gels in your mind, however, it will open up new ways of thinking about coding.    The benefit of the above is that once you populate your dictionary the remainder of the code is early bound -- i.e. compile time checking for mispellings & type mismatches.  Early binding will make you happy in the long run ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need nested `Dictionary` instances:

```
var outer = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();
var inner = new Dictionary<String, String>();
inner["align"] = "left";
// ...
outer["Event1"] = inner;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better of if you used `XDocument` instead of `XmlReader`. That way, you can just load the XML and then immediately access it, almost the way you want:

```
XElement settingsParent = …;

var event1Color = settingsParent.Elements()
                                .Single(s => s.Attribute("name").Value == "event1")
                                .Attribute("color").Value;
```

Granted, it's much more verbose than your code using associative array, but on the other hand, you don't have to write any conversion code.